# distribute version only with iPA file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipa

I need to upload a new version of a client of mine but i have only the iPA file from him.
Is it possible to distribue new version using xCode 4.5?

Couldnt find the right answer.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, impossible. New version -> new compilation -> need source code.

Comment: Thanks Mundi, thats what i thought, only wanted to make sure!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an IPA file for an app that has been built, and your device has been provisioned, you can use iTunes to upload it to your device.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no.  In order to distribute the app you'll need a distribution (app store) provisioning profile from the account.  Unless you have such a profile and the ability to log into the App Store account (AND be Team Lead if it's a business account) you're out of luck.